# How to catch the load event for a window, after location.replace (url change)

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

So I opened a window with `window.open('https://example.com/foo')`. I am on the same domain and need to listen for the load event.

The load event triggers for the first `window.open` but I can't get another event when i change the url with `window.replace('https://example.com/bar')`

### CodeSandbox

[image: Edit static]

1. Open the browser console
2. Click the open button (observe the log in the console)
3. Click the switch button (observe that nothing gets logged)

### Full example

```
let open = null;
document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  open = window.open('https://523k29z484.codesandbox.io/pages/foo.html');
  open.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('this fires'));
});

document.getElementById('switch-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  open.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('before change does not fire'));
  open.location.replace('https://523k29z484.codesandbox.io/pages/bar.html');
  open.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('after change does not fire'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by carefully chaining the following code.

```
open.location.replace('https://211vv50z30.codesandbox.io/pages/bar.html');

// old page unloaded
open.addEventListener('unload', () => {
  // we can only add the load event after one tick
  setTimeout(() => {
    open.addEventListener('load', () => console.log('gotcha'));
  }, 0);
});
```

location.replace -> unload -> setTimeout (one tick) -> load

### CodeSandbox

[image: Edit fixed window load problem]